# Insert text generated in php in the html

Tags: php

We can do

```
<img src="page.php" />
```

to display an image generated in php.

How can I do something like `<div src="page.php" ></div>` to display a text generated in php?

P.S: I know we can do `<?php echo ""; ?>` but my goal is to show people that it's from php, and not to modify the html content (only in memory).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you may be looking for `<iframe src="page.php"></iframe>`

Comment: <div src="page.php" ></div> is not even valid html! What do you want to do?

Comment: @BrettZamir It's surely that! Post it as an answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<iframe src="page.php"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without javascript: `<iframe src="page.php"></iframe>`

Comment: The same result without javascript is always better

Answer (score 0):

You can load a php generate page into a div using jquery and ajax.

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

then call the javascript to load it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#result').load('page.php');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
<div><?php include('somefile.php') ?></div>
```

And in somefile.php you would have:

```
<?php
     echo "Some Text";
?>
```

Comment: Yes, but I said `my goal is to show people that it's from php` and like that, they can't even know that there is a php file.

Comment: Then you should specify you wanted to see "somefile.php" in your rendered source. "Show people that it's from php" could mean another developer can see what to edit.